# How to optimize object's memory size while using multiple inheritance with visual studio compiler?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

```
#include <iostream>
class A {};
class B {};
class C : public A, public B {
    int a;
};

int main() {
    std::cout << sizeof(C) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

If I compile above code using cl, the output is '8'. While compiling with g++, the output will be '4'.

Without multiple inheritance the output will be '4' with both compilers.

Thanks.

Comment: Are those 4 bytes really important?

Comment: @JosephMansfield In 3d game, it's very important because there will be  millions instances of vector3d.

Comment: What happens if B derives from A and then C derives from B? Could that help you?

Comment: @AlanStokes Yeah, I have tried it. It works but is not elegant...

Comment: Did you enable compiler optimizations? I'd be surprised if VC++ didn't implement empty base class optimization...

Comment: Of cource. I build the project in release version. And I have tried /O1 /O2 /Ox /Ot /Os, all of these options didn't work.

Comment: It is actually 1 byte (a class cannot have a zero size) + 3 bytes of padding + 4 bytes for the int = 8 bytes.  Add an *int* member to A and you'll see it is still 8 bytes.  Hard to imagine it is a real problem, consider to not write classes without any state.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer why it is 8-byte: [Why empty base class optimization is not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12701469/why-empty-base-class-optimization-is-not-working)

The solution is to chain all base classes. To be elegant, we could write like this:

```
template <class Base = empty_base>
class A1 : public Base {};

template <class Base = empty_base>
class A2 : public Base {};

template <class Base =empty_base>
class A3 : public Base {};

class C : public A1<A2<A3> > { int c; };
```

You can find more code in this pattern in "boost/operators.hpp"